# How can I get sparce confusion matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to "rolling Random forest classification" for timeseries data.
The model classifies two classes. It changes the data samples and fits several times, which I mean "rolling".

I get confusion matrixes for each sample sets and sum up as final step.
but in several sample sets, only one class exit.
In this case, matrix shows up like below:

[[22]]

I want to make this case like below;

[[22, 0]
 [0, 0]]

Do you have any idea to make this happen?

Comment: If you keep track of what class is being scored, you can manually create one yourself.

Comment: thank you for answering.
yeah you're right, but in my case, I make so many different versions of model and data periods, so I cant do manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

obs = np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)
pred = np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)
vals = np.ones(50).astype('int')

con = sparse.coo_matrix((vals, (pred, obs)))
print (con.todense())
```